# Struts 1.2: html:options does not find a collection from a bean

Tags: java, jsp, struts

I have a Struts page which displays the following in a form in my JSP:

```
            <html:select property="value">
                <html:options collection="valueNext"/> 
            </html:select>
```

In the Java form, the getters both exist:

```
    public AValue getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public List<AValue> getValueNext() {
        return value.next();
    }
```

Yet, when I try to display the page, I always have an error message telling me the following:

> Cannot find bean under name valueNext

I do not understand why Struts would find the `value` and not `valueNext` (yes, I have removed the `html:options` lines, and it works).

I am quite new to Struts, but it appears to me that both are in the same scope. Can somebody enlighten me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found it (thanks to the help of another contributor).

I am not using the right tag: `html:options` is to use when you invoke another bean.

To invoke a property of your form, I should use `html:optionsCollection` instead. The following JSP works just fine:

```
        <html:select property="value">
            <html:optionsCollection property="valueNext"/> 
        </html:select>
```

(Struts documentation: [html:options](http://struts.apache.org/development/1.x/struts-taglib/tlddoc/html/options.html) and [html:optionsCollection](http://struts.apache.org/development/1.x/struts-taglib/tlddoc/html/optionsCollection.html))